# Multilingual $http requests in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a multilingual routing and $http requests for my AngularJS application but I couldn't find any solution so far..It would be nice if you help.

Example:

www.somewebsite.com/ar/home **Case 1 If the user choose the arabic language**

www.somewebsite.com/en/home **Case 2 If the user choose the english language**

Each link has different CSS....
If the user chosed the Ar version of the website, the website is going to load the rtl.css file else rtl.css won't be loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ng_cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) to save the user language.

Then when you have to make an http request, just make a switch, but that's not the best way to do it.

The best way should be a AngularJS service which would get the language from the cookies if there is one, if not, pick one by default (english for instance), then change your content.

Anyway this question is really well documented, for instance :
http://blog.novanet.no/creating-multilingual-support-using-angularjs/